Value in update is not treated as a condition
I am trying to implement the solution provided in this post using Spring Mongo:
import org.bson.Document;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Update;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class YourService {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public void conditionalUpdate() {
        Query query = new Query(); // match all documents

        Document condExpression = new Document("$cond",
            new Document("if", new Document("$eq", List.of("$role", "admin")))
                .append("then", "$name")      // keep the existing value if role is "admin"
                .append("else", "<new name>") // set to a new value otherwise
        );

        Update update = new Update().set("name", condExpression).set("phone", "<new number>");

        mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, update, "users");
    }
}

Unfortunately internally the condition document is converted to a string and name field is updated with a following value:
"name": "{\"$cond\": {\"if\": {\"$eq\": [\"$role\", \"admin\"]}, ..."

How to overcome this? Thanks in advance!
MongoDB v6.0.x, spring-data-mongodb v4.1.12
P.S. Mind that one cannot move condition from update to query as there are more fields to update unconditionally.

The linked post on the top of your question uses Update with Aggregation. In Spring Data MongoDB you use AggregationUpdate class to specify that update operation.

Yes, using AggregationUpdate worked, thanks! Welcome to answer the post.
